# How to prevent httpx timeout in python?

Tags: python, httpx

I am trying to scrape tokopedia here. When I use raw codes, it works and the json is returned. However when I tried to use it as a variable, it reads time out.
website:https://www.tokopedia.com/samudrasembako/regal-marie-roll-230-gram?extParam=ivf%3Dfalse&src=topads
Here's the code

```
!pip install fake_useragent
!pip install httpx
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import httpx

tokopedia=['https://www.tokopedia.com/samudrasembako/regal-marie-roll-230-gram?extParam=ivf%3Dfalse&src=topads']
for url in tokopedia:
  ua = UserAgent().random
  product_key=url.split(".com")[1].split("/")[2].split("?")[0]
  shopdomain=url.split(".com")[1].split("/")[1].split("?")[0]
  payload={
    "operationName":"PDPGetLayoutQuery",
    "variables":
      {"shopDomain":f"{shopdomain}",
      "productKey":f"{product_key}",
       "layoutID":"",
       "apiVersion":1,
       "userLocation":
        {"cityID":"176",
         "addressID":"0",
         "districtID":"2274",
         "postalCode":"",
         "latlon":""},
       "extParam":""},
       "query":"fragment ProductVariant on pdpDataProductVariant {\n  errorCode\n  parentID\n  defaultChild\n  sizeChart\n  totalStockFmt\n  variants {\n    productVariantID\n    variantID\n    name\n    identifier\n    option {\n      picture {\n        urlOriginal: url\n        urlThumbnail: url100\n        __typename\n      }\n      productVariantOptionID\n      variantUnitValueID\n      value\n      hex\n      stock\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  children {\n    productID\n    price\n    priceFmt\n    optionID\n    optionName\n    productName\n    productURL\n    picture {\n      urlOriginal: url\n      urlThumbnail: url100\n      __typename\n    }\n    stock {\n      stock\n      isBuyable\n      stockWordingHTML\n      minimumOrder\n      maximumOrder\n      __typename\n    }\n    isCOD\n    isWishlist\n    campaignInfo {\n      campaignID\n      campaignType\n      campaignTypeName\n      campaignIdentifier\n      background\n      discountPercentage\n      originalPrice\n      discountPrice\n      stock\n      stockSoldPercentage\n      startDate\n      endDate\n      endDateUnix\n      appLinks\n      isAppsOnly\n      isActive\n      hideGimmick\n      isCheckImei\n      minOrder\n      __typename\n    }\n    thematicCampaign {\n      additionalInfo\n      background\n      campaignName\n      icon\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductMedia on pdpDataProductMedia {\n  media {\n    type\n    urlOriginal: URLOriginal\n    urlThumbnail: URLThumbnail\n    urlMaxRes: URLMaxRes\n    videoUrl: videoURLAndroid\n    prefix\n    suffix\n    description\n    variantOptionID\n    __typename\n  }\n  videos {\n    source\n    url\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductHighlight on pdpDataProductContent {\n  name\n  price {\n    value\n    currency\n    __typename\n  }\n  campaign {\n    campaignID\n    campaignType\n    campaignTypeName\n    campaignIdentifier\n    background\n    percentageAmount\n    originalPrice\n    discountedPrice\n    originalStock\n    stock\n    stockSoldPercentage\n    threshold\n    startDate\n    endDate\n    endDateUnix\n    appLinks\n    isAppsOnly\n    isActive\n    hideGimmick\n    __typename\n  }\n  thematicCampaign {\n    additionalInfo\n    background\n    campaignName\n    icon\n    __typename\n  }\n  stock {\n    useStock\n    value\n    stockWording\n    __typename\n  }\n  variant {\n    isVariant\n    parentID\n    __typename\n  }\n  wholesale {\n    minQty\n    price {\n      value\n      currency\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  isCashback {\n    percentage\n    __typename\n  }\n  isTradeIn\n  isOS\n  isPowerMerchant\n  isWishlist\n  isCOD\n  isFreeOngkir {\n    isActive\n    __typename\n  }\n  preorder {\n    duration\n    timeUnit\n    isActive\n    preorderInDays\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductCustomInfo on pdpDataCustomInfo {\n  icon\n  title\n  isApplink\n  applink\n  separator\n  description\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductInfo on pdpDataProductInfo {\n  row\n  content {\n    title\n    subtitle\n    applink\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductDetail on pdpDataProductDetail {\n  content {\n    title\n    subtitle\n    applink\n    showAtFront\n    isAnnotation\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductDataInfo on pdpDataInfo {\n  icon\n  title\n  isApplink\n  applink\n  content {\n    icon\n    text\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductSocial on pdpDataSocialProof {\n  row\n  content {\n    icon\n    title\n    subtitle\n    applink\n    type\n    rating\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nquery PDPGetLayoutQuery($shopDomain: String, $productKey: String, $layoutID: String, $apiVersion: Float, $userLocation: pdpUserLocation, $extParam: String) {\n  pdpGetLayout(shopDomain: $shopDomain, productKey: $productKey, layoutID: $layoutID, apiVersion: $apiVersion, userLocation: $userLocation, extParam: $extParam) {\n    requestID\n    name\n    pdpSession\n    basicInfo {\n      alias\n      createdAt\n      isQA\n      id: productID\n      shopID\n      shopName\n      minOrder\n      maxOrder\n      weight\n      weightUnit\n      condition\n      status\n      url\n      needPrescription\n      catalogID\n      isLeasing\n      isBlacklisted\n      menu {\n        id\n        name\n        url\n        __typename\n      }\n      category {\n        id\n        name\n        title\n        breadcrumbURL\n        isAdult\n        isKyc\n        minAge\n        detail {\n          id\n          name\n          breadcrumbURL\n          isAdult\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      txStats {\n        transactionSuccess\n        transactionReject\n        countSold\n        paymentVerified\n        itemSoldFmt\n        __typename\n      }\n      stats {\n        countView\n        countReview\n        countTalk\n        rating\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    components {\n      name\n      type\n      position\n      data {\n        ...ProductMedia\n        ...ProductHighlight\n        ...ProductInfo\n        ...ProductDetail\n        ...ProductSocial\n        ...ProductDataInfo\n        ...ProductCustomInfo\n        ...ProductVariant\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
  }
  headers={
    'origin': 'https://www.tokopedia.com',
    'referer': f'{url}',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': "Windows",
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-device': 'desktop',
    'x-source': 'tokopedia-lite',
    'x-tkpd-akamai': 'pdpGetLayout',
    'x-tkpd-lite-service': 'zeus',
    'x-version': '53ac990'
  }
  client= httpx.Client()
  resp=client.post("https://gql.tokopedia.com/graphql/PDPGetLayoutQuery",json=payload,headers=headers)
```

Can someone please help? So that the above code runs and returns the json.

Answer (score -1):

## https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#timeout-configuration

client = httpx.Client(timeout=None)  # Disable all timeouts by default.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34528293)